# Concatenate two double matrices

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to write a simple function to concatenate two 2D double matrices.

```
double** concat(double **upmat,double **lowmat,int row,int col,int filecount)
{

double **temp=new double* [filecount*row];
for(int i=0;i<row*filecount;i++){
    temp[i]=new double [col];
}

if (filecount>1)
    std::copy(upmat,upmat+(filecount-1)*row*col,temp);
std::copy(lowmat,lowmat+row*col,temp+(filecount-1)*row*col);


return temp;
}
```

This function returns a 2D pointer. When I tried to access data from that pointer it shows invalid memory access error!!

Comment: Should the for loop do `row` lines or `filecount*row` lines?

Comment: @stark thank you very much.

Comment: @Stark now it copies the content of upper matrix; but not the lower matrix!! Could you help me with this?

Comment: You need to copy each row in the for loop as you allocate it.  You can't copy it in one instruction because your cols are nested in the rows.  Right now you are leaking memory because you are overwriting the pointers in temp that you just allocated.

Comment: what are `row` and `filecount` ? maybe use better variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp, low, and high are all `double**` (pointer to pointer to double) , but you do std::copy as if they are `double*` (pointer to double) .

Comment: I got it. Thanks. :)